# Any known values of density for spinal cord (pig or human)?

Tags: central-nervous-system

Need to know the density of spinal cord tissue to evaluate the shear modulus from ultrasound elastography (shear wave velocity) measurements, but need the density of the tissue to compute this.

I am a physicist by trade so unaware of whether white and gray matter have homogeneous properties in the CNS as a whole or whether they are different in the brain and spinal cord.

Could do with density (g cm^-3 or equivalent) of white matter, gray matter or of the cord as a whole.

Also if there are any sources so i can cite this this would be most useful.